# How to make a picturebox rotate only once in c#?

Tags: c#, forms, rotation

I'm making a mini game. I want to rotate my player with this code when I turn left and right `picPlayer.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX)` My moving code is:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   //when one of the movement keys are pressed, 
   //makes it's variable true.

   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right || e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
    {
        moveRight = true;
    }
}
```

Also, my timer's program is:

```
private void tmrMovementPlayer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //whenever right arrow is pressed,
    if (moveRight == true)
    {
        //decrease the x variable by 5 (moves right)
        x = x + PLAYER_SPEED;
        //check for boundaries (if the player is out of the screen)
        if (x >= this.ClientSize.Width - picPlayer.Width)
        {
            //if yes, set it back to the boundary.
            x = this.ClientSize.Width - picPlayer.Width;
        }
        //check the subprogram for info
        MovePlayer();
    }
}
```

What should I do at this point? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to the other answer, I found the solution. It was a little bit different. I created another boolean called "goingRight" just for the rotation.

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right || e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
{
    //make move right true
    moveRight = true;
    //if i was going left,
    if (goingRight == false)
    {
        //say it im going right
        goingRight = true;
        //and flip it (only if i was going left before)
        picPlayer.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
    }
}
```

Again, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like...

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //when one of the movement keys are pressed, 
    //makes it's variable true.

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right || e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
    {
        if (!moveRight)
        {
            picPlayer.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX)
            moveRight = true;
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the I did it for both of my directions. It doesn't work because when I stop and click right again, it rotates again. Lets say im going right. When I stop, it still looks at the right direction, but when I press right again, it rotates it again and looks at left.

Comment: And... what does (!moveRight) mean? I mean, what does ! mean in that code?

Comment: ! means boolean opposite.  So if moveRight was currently false, !moveRight would evaluate to true.

Comment: "Lets say im going right. When I stop, it still looks at the right direction, but when I press right again, it rotates it again and looks at left."  In my mind, stopping after going right means I'm still facing right, so why would moveRight be false?  Perhaps you should have a different variable to track the currently facing direction and set the image based on that instead.